# programming a serie of words with a loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop

I have a macro which checks for each cell of the first line of my 60 first columns, if the cell is empty, the macro automatically fills up the cell with the word “boubou” for every empty cell. However, I would like to fill up the empty cell not with the same word each time. For example, if the macro detects a first empty cell, I would like that it fills up with the word “boubou”, then for the second empty cell found, I would like that it fills up with the word “boubou2”, ”, then for the third empty cell found, I would like that it fills up with the word “boubou3” and so on…
Please find my VBA code below.
If someone knows the solutions, it would be fantastic.

Many thanks
Xavi

```
Sub hdfhgfdhhgf()
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 60
If IsEmpty(Cells(1, i).Value) = True Then
 Cells(1, i).Value = "boubou"
 End If
 Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already had the code, just needed to add `& i`

```
Option Explicit
Sub hdfhgfdhhgf()

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 60
        If IsEmpty(Cells(1, i)) Then Cells(1, i).Value = "boubou" & i
    Next i

End Sub
```

Thought the first word will be "boubou1"